# Express: Download returns empty file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Whenever I'm hitting the endpoint, I keep getting empty file while locally generated file is correct and contains all the fields I need. I've tried piping directly to response but I would be getting:

> Cannot pipe, not readable

Of course there might be something I'm doing wrong.

[Similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311108/download-returning-empty-file?rq=1)

```
const PORT = 3000;

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('fast-csv');

const app = express();

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Express server is listening on ${PORT}`);
});

app.get('/rates/csv', (req, res) => {

let ws = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/tmp/rates.csv');

csv.write([
    ["a", "b"],
    ["a1", "b1"],
    ["a2", "b2"]
], {headers: true})
    .pipe(ws);

console.log('FILE SAVED');

res.download(ws.path, 'rates.csv')
});
```

Comment: while I found workaround with `res.attachment` `rs.pipe`. I still would like to know why DOWNLOAD method didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pipe a writable stream to another writable stream.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93

Comment: Good link. Thank you. Yea I created readStream which I piped to res. In combination with attachment.
`let rs = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/tmp/rates.csv');`
`res.attachment("rates.txt");`
`rs.pipe(res);`